# Geometric/Topologic Tables Bibliography

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I'm Looking for a book, that can serve as a "compilation" sort of "table book" of typical spaces, ex. Projective Spaces, Torus, Steiner's Roman, and stuff like that...
i know where to find references and do figure out some proprieties but for some things, would be more confortable to have a "fix" reference for this things and not necessarily go book by book...

Any Ideas?

In analogy kind of Abramowitz but for Geometry/Topology

Answer (score 0):

The book [**Counterexamples in Topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) would seem to fit your description, though it doesn't seem to contain the specific examples you've listed. The link is to the Wikipedia page; [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X) is the book on Amazon.